# Frame Layout for navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am implementing Navigation Drawer in my Main Activity. When I load a fragment for the drawer item, the action bar gets overlapped above the fragment.I am required to give a top margin of about 48 dp, so that my views come below the action bar. How can I bring my fragment layout below the ActionBar?

Comment: Post your xml code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

use this in your layout it changes in size based on screen configuration automatically

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial:
[android-sidebar-navigation-drawer-with-icons](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-sidebar-navigation-drawer-with-icons/)